# Saying that a variable is a member of an array in typescript

Tags: typescript

Suppose that I have an array `const a = ['apple', 'orange']`.

Basically, I want to convert this to something like:

```
type MyType = 'apple' | 'orange';
```

I don't know if this is possible with Typescript. I have searched a lot and haven't find a way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just write `const a = ['apple', 'orange']`, the compiler will infer `a` to be of type `string[]`, and any information about the [literal](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) `"apple"` or `"orange"` values will be lost.  This is reasonable default behavior since, quite often, people want to add/remove `string` values from a string array.  But it's not helpful for your use case; it's too wide.  You want the compiler to infer a narrower type for `a`.

One way to do this is with a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions):

```
const a = ['apple', 'orange'] as const;
// const a: readonly ["apple", "orange"]
```

Now the compiler infers that `a` is a [readonly tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#readonly-tuple-types) of the literal string types `"apple"` and `"orange"`, in that order.

---

At this point you have enough information to compute `MyType`:

```
type MyType = (typeof a)[number];
// type MyType = "apple" | "orange"
```

This is using the [`typeof` type operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html#the-typeof-type-operator) to find the type of `a` (which is `readonly ["apple", "orange"]`), and then perform an [indexed access](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) on it with the `number` index.  Since `(typeof a)` is an array type, then if you index into `a` with a `number`, you will get a value of the `"apple"` or `"orange"` literal types.  Hence, `(typeof a)[number]` is `"apple" | "orange"`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhjAvDA2gcjgB0wGwKZoA0MaIATnGAOYEC68EMokUA3AFAD0nT408ALhhk8cACbgcAT1QAiLLjyzis8pRqza7dlCmY8MALJSAKnoPIAFLv0gAZvACUKMAFcAtgCM8ZWh24wNgbGZvpIMPLY+LIwAD4RatRKQA)